# JsonUtility worked earlier but after a compile in VS, it stopped i think

Tags: unity-game-engine

Untiies JsonUtility class creates an object, but does not set it's variables.

I'm sure the code is correct, since it worked earlier today. Also tjeked with guides.

```cs
public class Player
{
    public int speed;
    public int health;
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

public class Testing : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TextAsset _textAsset;

    void Start()
    {
        Player p = JsonUtility.FromJson<Player>(_textAsset.text);
        Debug.Log(p.speed); // should print 5
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "player": {
        "speed": 5,
        "health": 3,
        "x": 0,
        "y": -4
    }
}
```

The above worked earlier today, and I'm unsure what made it stop. And did input the correct text asset file.

What I think broke it. Went into Visual Studio and compilede once.

I triede to make a new project, but with no success.

The assets are in a Unity package. The following link expires in 7 days.
https://easyupload.io/dkmrnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your JSON is not the structure your code expects.

First of all yes your player class needs to be

```
[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    // fields here NO properties!
}
```

However, your JSON is further nested!

It either needs to be only

```
{
    "speed": 5,
    "health": 3,
    "x": 0,
    "y": -4
}
```

Or you need an according wrapper class

```
[Serializable]
public class JsonRoot
{
    public Player player;
}
```

and then you would need to do

```
Player p = JsonUtility.FromJson<JsonRoot>(_textAsset.text).player;
```

Comment: Yea thanks. I'm a bit retarded, should follow the guidlines better. Before saking for this stuff. Think this is a dup question, should i delete it or nah?